# JMeter - How to pass Multiline response data to the ForEach Controller request

Tags: java, performance, jmeter

facing problem with copying multiple message from one request response and passing to forEachContoller request in jmeter. i have tried with handle response data with RegEx and passing to forEachContr. but it is passing only one value, not passing multiple values

```
Jmeter_Domian
Google
Yahoo
Facebook
```

i want to pass this response data to next forEachController request.

${Jmeter_Domian} is my regEx variable and ${Jmeter_Domian1} is my forEachController Output variable.

```
{
    "request": [
        {
            "Domain": "${Jmeter_Domian1}"
        },
        {
            "Domain": "${Jmeter_Domian1}"
        },
        {
            "Domain": "${Jmeter_Domian1}"
        }
]
```

i have executed above scenario but it is passing

```
{
    "request": [
        {
            "Domain": "Google"
        },
        {
            "Domain": "Google"
        },
        {
            "Domain": "Google"
        }
]
```

But expected response is

```
{
    "request": [
        {
            "Domain": "Google"
        },
        {
            "Domain": "Yahoo"
        },
        {
            "Domain": "Facebook"
        }
]
```

can anyone help me from this. Thanks!

Comment: wouldn't changing to `{"request":[{"Domain":"${Jmeter_Domian1}"},{"Domain":"${Jmeter_Domian2}"},{"Domain":"${Jmeter_Domian3}"}]}` help?

Comment: no @dkb when am using as per your scenario in response am getting `${Jmeter_Domian1}
${Jmeter_Domian2}` not updating the variable value.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ForEach Controller for variables concatenation, it can only be used for iterating the values one by one.

If you want to create a [JSON](http://json.org/) from 3 [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you need to do some scripting using any [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) language, example code:

```
def data = new ArrayList()

1.upto(vars.get('Jmeter_Domian_matchNr') as int, {
    def entry = new groovy.json.internal.LazyMap()
    entry.put('Domain', vars.get("Jmeter_Domian_" + it))
    data.add(entry)
})

def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
builder(request: data.collect { it })

vars.put('myRequest', builder.toPrettyString())

log.info('Generated request: ')
log.info(vars.get('myRequest'))
```

Demo:

[image]

You will be able to access generated value as `${myRequest}` where required.